# JavaScript: How to optimize team balancing program that runs based on Greedy Algorithm?

Tags: javascript, algorithm, optimization

I've written a simple JavaScript program using jQuery that takes in a group of players and breaks them into teams of similar skill level. I spent a lot of time looking at the best way to sort the teams and settled on using a [Greedy Algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_problem#The_greedy_algorithm). This works when splitting the group of players into 2 teams. However, when breaking players into more than 2 teams the subsets are close but not always optimal.

Example: Splitting 20 players whose skill levels can be represented as (11,10,8,8,7,7,7,7,7,6,5,5,5,4,4,3,3,2,1,1) with an average skill value of 5.55 into 4 teams.

The greedy algorithm breaks them into the following 4 subsets

- Team 1: (11,7,5,3,3) Sum: 29 Average: 5.8
- Team 2: (10,7,5,4,2) Sum: 28 Average: 5.6
- Team 3: (8,7,7,4,1) Sum: 27 Average: 5.4
- Team 4: (8,7,6,5,1) Sum: 27 Average: 5.4

But the optimal teams, in this case, are actually

- Team 1: (11,7,**4**,3,3) Sum: 28 Average: 5.6
- Team 2: (10,7,5,4,2) Sum: 28 Average: 5.6
- Team 3: (8,7,7,**5**,1) Sum: 28 Average: 5.6
- Team 4: (8,7,6,5,1) Sum: 27 Average: 5.4

I'm wondering if anyone has any insights into what I can add to help make sure the program finds the optimal teams when splitting a group into more than 2 teams. (Also this is my first question on here so please let me know if there's any information I can add or clarify to make this better.)

Answer (score 0):

The following might not work for all cases, but it should be a slight improvement over the simple "greedy" algorithm:

```js
var sk=[11,10,8,8,7,7,7,7,7,6,5,5,5,4,4,3,3,2,1,1],n=4;
function greedy(arr,n){
  const asm=arr=>arr.reduce((a,c)=>a+c,0);
  let lim=Math.ceil(asm(arr)/n),
      loopend=sk.length*n;
      srt=arr.slice(0).sort((a,b)=>b-a),
      dist=[...Array(n)].map(()=>[]);
  for (let i=0; srt.length && i<loopend ; i++) {
    if (asm(dist[i%n])+srt[0]<=lim) dist[i%n].push(srt.shift());
  }
  console.log("lim:",lim);
  if (srt.length) console.log(lim,"Not all elements were distributed!")
  return dist
}

var res=greedy(sk,n);

console.log(res);
console.log("sums:",res.map(a=>a.reduce((s,c)=>s+c)));
```

Basically I follow the rules of the greedy algorithm, but before I `.push()` an element into one of the target arrays I check, whether the resulting sum would be more than the limit `lim` (a value calculated before on the basis of the total sum divided by the number of divisions).

In my function I calculate the sums for each sub-array freshly within each iteration (using `asm()`). This can of course be optimised by providing accumulating variables and only checking against the those and the new additional value.